# jest Error : elements.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to cover this code by test :

```
export default class {
  constructor({ document, onNavigate, firestore, localStorage }) {
    this.document = document
    this.onNavigate = onNavigate
    this.firestore = firestore
    const buttonNewBill = document.querySelector(`button[data-testid="btn-new-bill"]`)
    if (buttonNewBill) buttonNewBill.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickNewBill)
    const iconEye = document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-testid="icon-eye"]`)
    if (iconEye) iconEye.forEach(icon => {
      icon.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.handleClickIconEye(icon))
    })
    new Logout({ document, localStorage, onNavigate })
  }

  handleClickNewBill = e => {
    this.onNavigate(ROUTES_PATH['NewBill'])
  }

  handleClickIconEye = (icon) => {
    const billUrl = icon.getAttribute("data-bill-url")
    const imgWidth = Math.floor($('#modaleFile').width() * 0.5)
    $('#modaleFile').find(".modal-body").html(`<div style='text-align: center;'><img width=${imgWidth} src=${billUrl} /></div>`)
    $('#modaleFile').modal('show')
  }
```

this is what tired to test the function handelClickIconEye

```
 test("Then i click on Action icon modal should be open", ()=>{
      const onNavigate=(pathname)=>{
        document.body.innerHTML=ROUTES({pathname})
      }
      Object.defineProperty(window,'localStorage',{value:localStorageMock})
      window.localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify({
        type:'Employee'
      }))
      const bill=new Bills({
      document,onNavigate,firestore:null,localStorage:window.localStorage})
      const html=BillsUI({data:bills})
      document.body.innerHTML=html
      const icons=screen.getAllByTestId('icon-eye')
      const handleClickIconEye1=jest.fn((e)=>bill.handleClickIconEye(e,icons))
      icons.forEach(icon=>{icon.addEventListener('click',handleClickIconEye1)
      fireEvent.click(icon)
    })
      expect(handleClickIconEye1).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

I don't understand why it gives me the error:
[image]

this is what HTML variable contain:
[image]

Comment: You really should use dataSet to reference data attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the Error by modifying my code like flowing:
actually, icons were NodeList type and instead of making forEach element apply the event, I apply the event just in the first element on the NodeList and the test passed

```
 test("Then i click on Action icon modal should be open", ()=>{
      const onNavigate=(pathname)=>{
        document.body.innerHTML=ROUTES({pathname})
      }
      Object.defineProperty(window,'localStorage',{value:localStorageMock})
      window.localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify({
        type:'Employee'
      }))
      const bill=new Bills({
      document,onNavigate,firestore:null,localStorage:window.localStorage})
      const html=BillsUI({data:bills})
      document.body.innerHTML=html
      const icons=screen.getAllByTestId('icon-eye')
      const handleClickIconEye1=jest.fn((e)=>bill.handleClickIconEye(e,icons[0]))
 
      fireEvent.click(icon[0])
      expect(handleClickIconEye1).toHaveBeenCalled() //test passed
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see exactly from the code you've shown how you imported render/document or what testing library you're using, however what I do know is that you can't just use DOM operations on code that isn't actually a DOM.  Your code probably previously worked becasue it was executed in a browser and now you're running it without any DOM.  The fix to that is to make sure that the elements you're trying to test on has actually been rendered to an actual DOM, i.e. `render` from `react-dom`.

The reason you're getting that issue is because `getAttribute` isn't a function, the object you're calling it on isn't recognized as an element.

Comment: actually, I don't use any library  like react on my project, in the file test I have been imported { fireEvent, getByRole, screen } from "@testing-library/dom" and user event too,and the icon is an element as it shows in pic HTML variable

Comment: Whatever you are using, you need to render your components to an actual DOM first before you can use DOM functions on them.  You also shouldn't have to manually create object properties like window, window should already exist on the DOM.  It's likely that your jest environment target might not be set to ````jsdom````.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the icon is defined
something like this :
`let icon = document.querySelector("your-element")`
which you want get that attributes

Comment: it's  defined when i used : const icons=screen.getAllByTestId('icon-eye') it return NodeList and i use forEach for every icon